# How do I link to XSD files using the Apache CXF Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm using the Apache `cxf-codegen-plugin` Maven plugin to try and generate Java classes from a WSDL file. I get the following error:

> `Part <parameters> in Message <{http://www.foo.com/bar}PushCommandSoapIn> referenced Type <{http://www.foo.com/bar}CommandMessage> can not be found in the schemas`

The type in question (`CommandMessage`) is defined in an XSD file that I've attempted to reference using the following POM file:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.11</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <wsdlOptions>
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/SomeService.wsdl</wsdl>
            <dependencies>
              <!-- Here I try to reference the XSD -->
              <dependency>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/SomeTypes.xsd</dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any suggestions of why I'm getting an error? I'm not sure adding a `<dependency>` is the correct way, but I struggled to find documentation that describes how to reference XSD files.

Here is the snippet from the WSDL file that refers to the missing type:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
      xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
      xmlns:bar="http://www.foo.com/bar" 
      targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/bar">
  <wsdl:message name="PushCommandSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="bar:CommandMessage" />
  </wsdl:message>
```

Here is the header and a snippet from the XSD file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/bar" 
      xmlns:bar="http://www.foo.com/bar" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
      elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
  ...
  <element name="CommandMessage" type="bar:CommandMessageType" substitutionGroup="bar:Message" final="#all" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Your wsdl would need a wsdl:types element in it that has a schema with an import in it.   Basically, the wsdl needs to know about the schema.

```
 <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.foo.com/bar" schemaLocation="bar.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to have resolved the issue. Is there a way to configure this within the plugin, rather than adjusting the WSDL file?

Comment: It seems wrong to have the WSDL containing a hard-coded path for the XSD file. That ought to be a build configuration issue.